# Represent postgres INET type in slick case class / table definition

Tags: postgresql, scala, ip-address, slick

Are there any possibilities of using the postgres INET type in a slick table definition?

I'm aware of https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg but it doesn't support the INET type.

Comment: What if you lie to Slick and tell it that it would be a String? Does that work? If yes you can go further and provide a TypeMapper from between SomeInetClass and String and then use that.

Comment: I'm really not sure how that would work.  I have a feeling it would be more trouble than its worth. In particular, because I'm using I'm doing comparison between an query parameter and the inet fields. So I do somethinglike ip_parameter <= ip_field. My immediate solution has been to hardcode the sql query and return back just the required projection which does not include an inet type.

Comment: @cvogt it is not possible to use `String` as slick tries to insert as character varying and this produces an `PSQLException` (at least for `macaddr` this is the case).

Comment: FYI: this is somehow related to https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/594

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for seeing this question so late.
Slick-pg  already support INET/MacAddr now, as required by [atomgregg](https://github.com/atomgregg).

If you saw it, you can try it, and any question pls talk to me in github issues.

*(p.s. stackoverflow wasn't always accessible in my country (China mainland).)*